# Module Federation with NextJS Using Independently Deploy Remote

Tags: next.js, webpack-module-federation

I'm having a hard time getting module federation to work in my NextJS app. The few examples I've seen online are examples that reference

### ReactJS - working

##### Remote

```
// my-project/site/webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'public/index.html' }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: 'myRemoteApp',
          filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            './App': './src/App',
          },
          shared: { react: { singleton: true }, 'react-dom': { singleton: true } },
        }),
    ],
};

// my-project/site/src/App.js
import React from 'react';
const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Some remote application...</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
export default App;
```

##### Host

```
// some-other-project/webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin = require('external-remotes-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      remotes: {
        myRemoteApp: 'myRemoteApp@https://my-remote-app.myorg.com/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: { react: { singleton: true }, 'react-dom': { singleton: true } },
    }),
    new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

### NextJS - not working

##### Remote

```
... same as 'ReactJS > Remote' above
```

##### Host

```
// my-srr-project/server/webpack.config.js
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack')
const NextFederationPlugin = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf')
...
module.exports = {
  name: 'my-host-app',
  plugins: [
    new NextFederationPlugin({
      name: 'host',
      filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        myRemoteApp: 'myRemoteApp@https://my-remote-app.myorg.com/remoteEntry.js',
      }
    })
  ]
}

// my-srr-project/pages/_app.tsx
const MyRemoteApp = dynamic(() => import('myRemoteApp/App'), {
  ssr: true,
});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  ...
  return (
    <>
      <MyRemoteApp /> <-- Try to use the remote app -->
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

The error that I'm getting is...

```
error - ./pages/_app.tsx:20:34
Module not found: Can't resolve 'myRemoteApp/App'
```

All of the examples like [nextjs-mf > Implementing the Plugin](https://github.com/module-federation/universe/tree/main/packages/nextjs-mf#implementing-the-plugin) and [module-federation-examples > host-app](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/nextjs-react/host-app/next.config.js) reference the remote app as something that's available on localhost but I don't see any references anywhere to an app that's truely remote - in my case, it's been deployed in aws s3 + cloudfront (which again... does work from a traditional ReactJS host but I can't figure out how to get it working from a NextJS app.) So yea, any advice? I feel like I'm maybe getting several pieces of this wrong. Would really appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

if your remote app is Next, the remoteEntry's path is 'myRemoteApp@https://my-remote-app.myorg.com/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js'.

Instead if "chunks" it also may be "ssr" folder in some cases. You can check if the file is accessible by yourself just going to  https://my-remote-app.myorg.com/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js in your browser.